# Zabbix alert on root login

Tags: zabbix

I have started using Zabbix and can see it is throwing alerts when things are changed such as /etc/passwd.

Goggling for 'zabbix alert on root login' is not bringing up any pointers - How would I go about having an alert on root login please?

Comment: Tough question.. The first thing which comes to my mind is using [zabbix_sender](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manpages/zabbix_sender) in a login script. But not sure, if this can be circumvented.

Comment: Parsing system logs would be another option (iirc zabbix can do that), but I personally dislike this.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't allow root logins altogether, because that's insecure. You should only allow regular user logins, and once logged in, the user can use `sudo` to execute commands as root.

That being said, why would you only check root logins? Checking regular user logins is just as important. Bots on the internet perform brute-force attacks for regular users all the time.

Either way, you need to check `/var/log/auth.log` for successful SSH logins. Checking log files requires active Zabbix agent checks. So first you need to make sure that active checks are working properly (see [this blog post](https://blog.zabbix.com/zabbix-log-file-monitoring/7378/)).

Secondly, the Zabbix user is (by default) running as the `zabbix` user. So it will not be able to read `/var/log/auth.log`, because that file is only readable by root and users in group `adm`. So you can add the `zabbix` user to the `adm` group. This allows Zabbix to read many log files ([source](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups)).

Finally, you need to create a monitoring item and trigger in Zabbix frontend.

Create an item:

```
Name: SSH successful authentication
Type: Zabbix agent (active)
Key: log[/var/log/auth.log,"Accepted .*",,,skip,\0]
```

Create a trigger for that item:

```
Name: Successful SSH authentication on {HOST.NAME}
Expression: {Template OS Linux - Extra:log[/var/log/auth.log,"Accepted .*",,,skip,\0].strlen()}>0 and {Template OS Linux - Extra:log[/var/log/auth.log,"Accepted .*",,,skip,\0].nodata(5m)}=0
```

Notice the `Accepted .*` regular expression in the item. This should match all types of SSH authentication, be it password authentication, or public key authentication. Of course, in your case, you can change the regex to only match logins from root. But as explained earlier, this makes no sense from a security perspective.

Also notice that I used `log[...]`, because this results in the responsible log line matched by the regex to be included in the notification email that Zabbix will send. That way, you can see in the email which user was authenticated.

Comment: In zabbix version 6.2.6 I had to use the following expression: `length(last(/SSH Service/log[/var/log/auth.log,"Accepted .*",,,skip,\0]))>0 and nodata(/SSH Service/log[/var/log/auth.log,"Accepted .*",,,skip,\0],5m)=0`

Answer (score 0):

For debian-based systems you need to parse `/var/log/auth.log` file like so:

`log.count[file,<regexp>,<encoding>,<maxproclines>,<mode>,<maxdelay>,<options>]`

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent

so in essence:

`log.count[/var/log/auth.log,*root*Accepted,,,skip]`